# Problem file disappear in Xcode when i rebooted

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to `Xcode` and swift in general, and I've started a little project for learning purpose.

I started the project 2 days ago and commit all the code on GitHub.
Yesterday I've started `Xcode` and all the files i manage to create disappear like it was a blank project (Only the `ContentView` was bugged (see screen).

The problem is that the file exist in my finder. But they are not existing on the project folder.

I may have missed something somewhere ?

Thx for the futur answer.

Project files:

[image: Project files]

finder files:

[image: finder files]

I've tried to re-import all files but it's killing the project.

I've tried to re-clone the git but files are like the first picture.

Comment: There is no ContentView.swift in your second image, that is your problem. Also the two image’s doesn’t match each other when it comes to the folders they contain so that is another possible issue.

Comment: Right click on the SleepySounds folder and “add files”. You can add the file you see in finder and then just delete the red one. You have likely moved it/deleted/renamed somewhere.

Comment: When a file is red it means that XCode has a reference of that file but the actual file is not present in the project's folders. Also, when you copy a file in your project make sure the "Copy if needed" option is selected.

Comment: Hi everyone thx for the answer !
Yeah joakim this is the problem when i open the project there is not the same folders that appear and i don't understand why ? 
I've tried to add files and rebuild the project like lorem ipsum say ... it work now but i lost a bit of developpement (pbly because my save was not updated). 
What does Copy if needed mean ? 
This is strange things because on the "git status" no files changed.
Is it a common problem of xcode or just a bug ?